# How to find a positive minimum of a function?

Tags: evaluation

How can I find a positive minimum of f and its corresponding R0?

```
f1 = BesselJ[0, 5.3*r]*(Sinh[7.85320462*z]/Sinh[3.92660231] - Sin[7.85320462*z]/Sin[3.92660231]); 
f2 = BesselJ[0, 5.3*r]*Sin[2*Pi*z]; 
f = (1/16)*((1/(Integrate[f1*(D[f2, {r, 2}] + (1/r)*D[f2, {r, 1}]), {z, -(1/2), 1/2}, {r, 0, R0}]*Integrate[f2*f1, {z, -(1/2), 1/2}, {r, 0, R0}]))*Integrate[f1*(D[f1, {r, 4}] + 2*(1/r)*D[f1, {r, 3}] + 2*D[f1, {r, 2}, {z, 2}] + 2*(1/r)*D[f1, {r, 1}, {z, 2}] + (1/r^2)*D[f1, {r, 2}] + D[f1, {z, 4}]), {z, -(1/2), 1/2},{r, 0, R0}]*Integrate[f2*(D[f2, {r, 2}] + (1/r)*D[f2, {r, 1}] + D[f2, {z, 2}]),{z, -(1/2), 1/2}, {r, 0, R0}])
FindMinimum[f, R0]
```

Clearly,`FindMinimum[]` is giving a negative minimum. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I see error messages indicating that the integral(s) do not converge. Are you not seeing those?

Comment: I am getting this error: FindMinimum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function value with MachinePrecision digit precision.